# Flash Catalyst for Android development?

Tags: flashcatalyst

Can Flash Catalyst CS5 or CS5.5 be used to create Android apps? I've been looking for the past few weeks and can't find a thing. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. But in conjunction with Flash Builder. I found this aeticle, it gives a workflow that may help.

http://flashcats.net/2011/07/16/how-to-run-flash-catalyst-cs5-5-projects-on-android-devices/